# Finding built-in Unity scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

If one would like to look into the core files of the Unity Engine, e.g: I've tried using the unity in-built "Fog" effect, but would like to see how it works on a deeper level (code). Is this something one can find, or is it encrypted in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take a look at [Unofficial unity decompiled repo](https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled) to check if there are sources you're looking for. It's a decompiled verison so there is no guarantee that it's the actual code. Also big part of Unity's sources is written in C++ and C# scripts just call this Unity's native C++ part, so it's really incomplete.

The other option is that some of big companies, Unity's partners which have highest support level, have access to official source code. So may be you're able to find someone with access to sources.